# Grails-Hiberante Lock wait timeout exceeded exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I´m getting the lock error timeouth exceeed exception when trying to save my caseToTag object who is a object of my domain.
The app gets all the cases who are not tag, try to tag it calling method1-method3,that modify the payment,so we save it and then when trying to save the case on                 caseToTag.save(flush: true) it throw that exception.
I'm using grails 2.2.4 and Mysql  5.6.21 -

```
class TagService {

    static transactional = false

    def userService
    def mediationService
    def paymentService
    def utilsService

    def tagCases(){
        def casesToTag = PpCase.findAllByStatusAndStatusDetail(PpCase.Status.PENDING, PpCase.StatusDetail.TAG)
        log.info "Se tienen ${casesToTag.size()} casos para taguear."
        casesToTag.each{ caseToTag ->
            try {
                caseToTag.payments.each{ payment ->
                    tagPayment(payment)
                }
                caseToTag.status = PpCase.Status.PENDING
                caseToTag.statusDetail = PpCase.StatusDetail.SF_INIT
            }
            catch(TagException e) {}
            caseToTag.save(flush: true)
        }
    }

    def tagPayment(payment){
        try{
           mathod1(payment)
           mathod2(payment)
           mathod3(payment)
           payment.save(failOnError: true)
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new TagException(e.getMessage())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you locking?

Comment: Well really didn´t cant figure what was causing the problem,I finished dropping all the data, becouse it seems to have an inconsistency.